# Problemas al instalar wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Tengo que instalar wordpress en un servidor, subí la carpeta al servidor como tal y quise empezar la instalación, pero al entrar me apareció este mensaje:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La subida de los archivos en si, me dio problemas, 29 archivos no se subieron y tuve que subirlos manualmente luego a cada carpeta que le correspondía

Hay algo que pueda hacer al respecto para corregirlo aparte de tener que subir nuevamente wordpress y descartar la instalación que estaba haciendo?

No se si servira de algo decirlo pero, al tratar de entrar en el navegador al sitio web haciendo uso de la ip del servidor al cual subi wordpress se carga setup-config.php que se encuentra en la carpeta wp-admin

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esa es la ruta que carga para ser exacto...

Agradecería que me pudieran ayudar

Comment: Hola, ¿cuentas con los permisos necesarios para realizar la instalación? Puede ser que el archivo requiera permisos de administrador.

Comment: Así es, en ese servidor ya se han hecho instalaciones de wordpress y funcionan bien de hecho, los pasos que segui fueron, descargar y descomprimir wordpress, luego copiar los archivos que están dentro de la carpeta que descomprimí y pegarlos en el directorio del servidor que cree para tener ahí mi instalación, estoy usando filezilla cliente

Comment: Hola te fijaste si tiene algún requerimiento de configuración específico? el servidor es local? no tenes softaculous en cpanel o algún otro scripts que automatiza la instalación de aplicaciones web

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que exportes tu sitio en local con el plugin  All one Migration y que con Softacpulos instales una aplicación de WordPress limpia y solo luego en el panel de administración tienes que instalar el plugin e importar el archivo que exportarse en local y ya está... Yo siempre lo hago así